# How to implement paging in a flex spark text area

Tags: apache-flex, textarea, paging, tlf

I am beginning to start implement a paging mechanism in my flex application and I am wondering where do I start off. Some examples that I have seen on internet work on plain text whereas I have the text in the text flow and I don't want to loose the formatting saved in the text flow. Any pointers will be helpful. 
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "paging"? When I think of paging, I typically think of DataGrid type paging.